# iPhone 6 counts 300 times more steps

Tags: iphone, ios, health.app

My iPhone with iOS 10.3 is **counting more than 300 times more steps** than usual. Sensor broken? Or what can I do?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved after updating to iOS 11.